# Are there any advantages to calling a code behind function from AJAX in .Net?

Tags: .net, ajax, vb.net

A  coworker and I are having a dispute on the way he does his coding. We're a .net shop and he's using AJAX calls.

He uses js to get all field names, then saves their values into a concatenated string. Then he calls the code behind function which takes the concatenated string and extracts the values from it. I'm from a .net background where I would just do all of this in the code behind.

Am I alone in thinking this is madness or is there any benefit to it?

```
 function saveData() {

        var sid = $('#<%= hfSID.ClientID %>').val();
        var tid = $find('<%= ddlTransporter.ClientID %>').get_selectedItem().get_value();
        var rate = $('#<%= txtTransporterRate.ClientID %>').val();
        var trucks = $('#<%= txtEstimatedTrucks.ClientID %>').val();
        var trips = $('#<%= txtEstimatedTurns.ClientID %>').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{sid: '" + sid + "', tid: '" + tid + "', rate: '" + rate + "', trucks: '" + trucks + "', trips: '" + trips + "'}",
            url: "/App/Schedule/ProfileScheduleTransporter.aspx/SaveData",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d == '') {

                    $('#divContent').addClass('hidden');
                    $('#divNew').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('#<%= hfMode.ClientID %>').val('1');
                }
                else {
                    showMessage("Warning", "400", "auto", data.d);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I alone in thinking this is madness

Yep. What he's doing doesn't involve a page load, it updates the current page in place.

Comment: Appreciate the answer! It's certainly not the case though. After the code behind function finishes, the page reloads.

Comment: Not according to the code as written. The "code behind function" as you call it is called as a separate network POST, received and translated to a JavaScript object for the `success` function to use. It has no control over what your browser is showing. So unless the `success` function initiates a reload (like with submit semantics), and it doesn't according to the code, then no reload will happen.